# CodeIgniter Profiler no longer displays after use of a layout hook

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've just set up a layout hook to streamline some of my own work, however, I've just realized my profiler has disappeared. I'm not quite sure what I need to do to get it back.

If I set `$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE` profiler re-appears, but breaks my layout of course. I'm assuming I've got to add a bit to my hook class, but I'm not sure where or what at this point.

```
class Layout {
    public function index()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();

        $current_output = $CI->output->get_output();

        if ($CI->uri->segment(1) == 'admin')
            $layout_file = APPPATH . 'views/admin/layout.php';
        else
            $layout_file = APPPATH . 'views/frontend/layout.php';
        $layout = $CI->load->file($layout_file, true);
        $mod_output = str_replace("{yield}", $current_output, $layout);

        //echo $layout_file;
        echo $mod_output;
    }
}
```

And of course, I've set `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` in my Controller.

Any suggestions or help would b greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the Profiler disappears is because it is up to the Output object to run the Profiler within the Output::_display() function.

As the [docs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html) explain, when you hook into the "display_override" point you prevent Output::_display() from being called.

If you want to output the Profiler within your Layout hook, you would need to do something like this:

```
class Layout {
    public function index()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();

        $current_output = $CI->output->get_output();

        if ($CI->uri->segment(1) == 'admin')
            $layout_file = APPPATH . 'views/admin/layout.php';
        else
            $layout_file = APPPATH . 'views/frontend/layout.php';
        $layout = $CI->load->file($layout_file, true);
        $mod_output = str_replace("{yield}", $current_output, $layout);

        $CI->load->library('profiler');

        if ( ! empty($CI->output->_profiler_sections))
        {
            $CI->profiler->set_sections($CI->output->_profiler_sections);
        }

        // If the output data contains closing </body> and </html> tags
        // we will remove them and add them back after we insert the profile data
        if (preg_match("|</body>.*?</html>|is", $output))
        {
            $mod_output  = preg_replace("|</body>.*?</html>|is", '', $mod_output);
            $mod_output .= $CI->profiler->run();
            $mod_output .= '</body></html>';
         }
         else
         {
            $mod_output .= $CI->profiler->run();
         }

        //echo $layout_file;
        echo $mod_output;
    }
}
```

All I've done to get this working is taking a block of code from Output::_display() that deals with rendering the Profiler output and inserting it with the rest of your hook.